# p:contextMenu within p:dataTable in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a problem related to a `<p:contextMenu>` within a `<p:dataTable>` of PrimeFaces. There is a `<p:commandLink>` and also some command buttons within columns in this table, when I open the context menu automatically inserted is the value of that column my variable, but the problem is this when I open this `<p:contexMenu>` menu by clicking the right button on top of one of these link command or command button the value of this column is not passed to variable.

This is my code.

```
<h:form id="form-arquivo-listar">
    <p:contextMenu id="menuArquivos" for="dataArquivos">
        <p:menuitem value="Baixar" icon="ui-icon-disk" url="../../arquivos/#{arquivoBean.arquivoSelecionado.nome}" target="arquivo"/>
        <p:menuitem value="Excluir" icon="ui-icon-close" actionListener="#{arquivoBean.excluir()}" update="form-arquivo-listar"/>
        <p:menuitem value="Transferir"  icon="ui-icon-extlink" actionListener="#{arquivoBean.getPastas()}" update=":formArquivoTransferir:treeArquivos" oncomplete="PF('arquivoTransferirDialog').show()"/>
    </p:contextMenu>

    <p:menubar model="#{arquivoBean.menu}"/>

    <p:dataTable id="dataArquivos" value="#{arquivoBean.objetos}" var="o" rowKey="#{o.id}" selection="#{arquivoBean.arquivoSelecionado}" selectionMode="single" styleClass="ui-datatable-no-border">

        <f:facet name="header">#{text['arquivo.pagina.listar.titulo']}</f:facet>

        <p:column style="width: 20px">
            <i class="#{o.tipo.icone}"></i>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="#{text['arquivo.pagina.form.nome']}" rendered="#{o.tipo.id != 5}">
            <p:link value="#{o.nomeOriginal}" href="../../arquivos/#{o.nome}" target="arquivo">
            </p:link>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="#{text['arquivo.pagina.form.nome']}" rendered="#{o.tipo.id == 5}">
            <p:commandLink  styleClass="link" id="link"  value="#{o.nomeOriginal}" actionListener="#{arquivoBean.alterarPasta(o.id)}" update=":form-arquivo-listar" >
            </p:commandLink>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="#{text['arquivo.pagina.form.publico']}" style="width: 50px">
            <h:outputText value="#{o.publico ? 'Sim' : 'Não'}" rendered="#{o.tipo.id != 5}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column style="width: 26px">
            <p:commandButton id="editarButton" title="Exibir" icon="ui-icon-search" update=":form-arquivo-listar:arquivo-detalhes" oncomplete="PF('arquivoDialog').show()" rendered="#{o.tipo.id != 5}">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{o}" target="#{arquivoBean.objeto}" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>

        <p:column style="width: 26px">
            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil" oncomplete="PF('cadastroArquivo').show()">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{o}" target="#{arquivoBean.objeto}" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>

        <p:column style="width: 26px">
            <p:commandButton id="excluirButton" title="#{text['arquivo.pagina.form.confirmacao.botao.titulo']}" icon="ui-icon-close" update=":form-arquivo-listar"  actionListener="#{arquivoBean.excluir(o.id)}">
                <p:confirm header="#{text['arquivo.pagina.form.confirmacao.titulo']}" icon="ui-icon-alert" message="#{text['arquivo.pagina.form.confirmacao.mensagem']}"  />
            </p:commandButton>
            <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-check" value="#{text['arquivo.pagina.form.confirmacao.sim']}" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" />
                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-close" value="#{text['arquivo.pagina.form.confirmacao.nao']}" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" />
            </p:confirmDialog>
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>

    <p:dialog id="arquivo-detalhes" widgetVar="arquivoDialog">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="4" style="margin:0 auto;">
            <h:outputLabel value="#{text['arquivo.pagina.form.id']}:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{arquivoBean.objeto.id}" />
            <h:outputLabel value="#{text['arquivo.pagina.form.arquivo']}:" />
            <h:graphicImage value="../../arquivos/#{arquivoBean.objeto.nome}" width="200" rendered="#{arquivoBean.isImagem()}"  />
            <p:media value="../../arquivos/#{arquivoBean.objeto.nome}" width="200" height="80" player="quicktime" rendered="#{arquivoBean.isAudio()}" />
            <p:media value="../../arquivos/#{arquivoBean.objeto.nome}" width="300" height="300" rendered="#{arquivoBean.isVideo()}"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

```
<p:dialog id="arquivoTransferirDialog" widgetVar="arquivoTransferirDialog">
    <h:form id="formArquivoTransferir">
        <p:growl id="msg" showDetail="false"/>
        <h:panelGrid columns="1">
            <p:tree id="treeArquivos" value="#{arquivoBean.raiz}"  var="arquivo" selection="#{arquivoBean.raizSelecionada}" selectionMode="single">
                <p:treeNode  expandedIcon="ui-icon ui-icon-folder-open" collapsedIcon="ui-icon ui-icon-folder-collapsed">
                    <h:outputText value="#{arquivo.nomeOriginal}" />
                </p:treeNode>
            </p:tree>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <p:commandButton value="Transferir" actionListener="#{arquivoBean.transferirArquivo()}" oncomplete="PF('arquivoTransferirDialog').hide()" update="formArquivoTransferir, :form-arquivo-listar:dataArquivos"/>
                <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" onclick="PF('arquivoTransferirDialog').hide()"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>

<p:dialog id="arquivoCriarPasta" widgetVar="arquivoCriarPasta">
    <h:form id="formCriarPasta">
        <p:growl id="msg" showDetail="false"/>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="Nome" />
            <p:inputText value="#{arquivoBean.objeto.nomeOriginal}" required="true"/>
            <h:column/>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <p:commandButton value="Salvar" actionListener="#{arquivoBean.salvarPasta()}" update="formCriarPasta,:form-arquivo-listar:dataArquivos" oncomplete="PF('arquivoCriarPasta').hide()"/>
                <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" onclick="PF('arquivoCriarPasta').hide()"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>

<p:dialog id="cadastroArquivo" header="#{text['arquivo.pagina.editar.titulo']}" widgetVar="cadastroArquivo" >
    <h:form id="form-arquivo-editar" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p:growl id="msg" showDetail="false"/>
        <h:inputHidden value="#{arquivoBean.objeto.id}" rendered="#{arquivoBean.objeto.id!=null}" />

        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin:20px">
            <p:outputLabel value="#{text['arquivo.pagina.form.arquivo']}" for="inputArquivo" />
            <p:fileUpload id="inputArquivo" value="#{arquivoBean.file}" required="true" label="#{text['arquivo.pagina.form.arquivo']}" mode="simple"
                          disabled="#{arquivoBean.objeto.id!=null and arquivoBean.objeto.id!=0}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="#{text['arquivo.pagina.form.nome']}" rendered="#{arquivoBean.objeto.id!=null and arquivoBean.objeto.id!=0}"  />
            <h:outputText value="#{arquivoBean.objeto.nomeOriginal}" rendered="#{arquivoBean.objeto.id!=null and arquivoBean.objeto.id!=0}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="#{text['arquivo.pagina.form.descricao']}" for="inputDescricao" />
            <p:inputTextarea id="inputDescricao" value="#{arquivoBean.objeto.descricao}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="#{text['arquivo.pagina.form.publico']}" for="inputPublico" />
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="inputPublico" value="#{arquivoBean.objeto.publico}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="#{text['arquivo.pagina.form.tipo']}" for="inputTipo" />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="inputTipo" value="#{arquivoBean.objeto.tipo}" required="true" label="#{text['arquivo.pagina.form.tipo']}"
                             converter="#{arquivoTipoBean.converter()}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{text['arquivo.pagina.form.tipo.default']}" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{arquivoTipoBean.selectObjetos}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px">
            <p:commandButton value="#{text['arquivo.pagina.form.salvar']}" update=":form-arquivo-editar,:form-arquivo-listar"
                             process="@form" actionListener="#{arquivoBean.salvar}" ajax="false" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```